# Check QGIS label visibility

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

Is there a way to check the visibility of a label in QGIS by feature?

Could the pyqgis library help?

I need to search for points where no label is shown:

[image: label missing]

Comment: Take a look at "[Show only point markers when their labels are shown](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217067/show-only-point-markers-when-their-labels-are-shown)". It appears that QGIS does not have an accessible property allowing you to detect whether a feature label is shown or not. The same is true for [the api](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLabel.html).

Comment: @Phil G, sounds like an answer.