# Hiding symbol if labels not displayed due to overlap using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, rendering

I have a trouble hiding points that don't have a label due to label overlap. In my example below, there are some points where the label is not shown.

How do I hide the points that don't display a label?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is still not possible.  Have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/218531/7849 and here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/217067/7849.

Answer (score 4):

It seem that you always display your label centered below the point, if that's really the case one suggestion is to not display your point as symbology but to incorporate it in your label (but take care to set up your label properly to display the point in the right location)

In the below picture you can see how to set it up (the grey circle are the original symbology point, shown here for demonstration purpose and to help setting up the right "y" offset for the label text and the label point)

[image]

This solution will only work if your label text is at a fixed position relative to the point you are labeling (It may be possible to use data defined override for the label point offset to make it work for non fixed label position but that probably wont be easy)

Comment: Nice workaround!

Comment: Great idea! The ambition to implement variable labels is aroused. 